Number of unique products $i\cdot j$ in $i,j\in1,2,\dots,n$ is at most $\frac{n^2}{\log\log n}$
These days I am thinking a well-studied problem:

Let $S_n=\{i\cdot j|1\le i\le j\le n\}$. Prove that $|S_n|\le\frac{n^2}{\log\log n}$.

The state-of-the-art bound is going to be by Kevin Ford, which implies $|S_n|\asymp
\frac{n^2}{(\log n)^c (\log\log n)^{3/2}}$, where $c = 1 - \frac{1+\log\log 2}{\log 2}$. But I know it is hard to prove this bound by myself. I am trying to prove a weaker bound: $|S_n|\le \frac{n^2}{\log\log n}$. I hope to get a more elementary (sorry if this is not well defined, but in my mind I think maybe not more advanced then high school math Olympiad) and shorter proof.
The first thing come to my mind is that from Noga Alon's book, a majority of numbers $\le n$ will have about $\log\log n$ prime factors, and also I have seen many posts on Math SE and math overflow and found this is the most helpful to me. I have struggled a bit but I still have a hard-time proving that thing continue from that link... The things I have tried is to prove that a majority of numbers if it can represent as a product of two integers $\le n$, then it can has $O(\log\log n)$ ways to do that by probability method, but failed... I also thought try to argue whether there is a canonial factoring for the product (say $i\cdot j$ with the smallest $i$) but still have the same issues (for large enough numbers, say $\ge n^2/4$, I cannot argue that there is a lot of ways to factor it.)
Finally, I also tried to bound the numbers $\le n^2$ with a prime factor $\ge n$, but it seems that there is only $\Theta(n^2)$ of them.
I am so sorry that this question has been asked several times and it is a already solved question, but what I look for is a way to deal with a slightly worse bound with alterative approach...
P.S. As @GerryMyerson suggested, I am going to elaborate the sourses I have read (as I said "I have seen many posts on Math SE and math overflow") and others. There has been numerous posts, as [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]. Among this, some of those focus on computation ([3], [4], [5]), [2] focus on the occurrance which is a bit deviating from the target of this problem. [6] asks for a precise bound which is still open. [4] also contains a link to the lecture where it cites Hardy-Ramanujuan theorem (as Fedor's post in [1] suggested.) These posts has little proof or a hint/link to the proof (with stricter bound.) If there is a desired proof (which I believe it will since this is a well studied problem) I am really not sure where to find it...
Prior to surveying on MST and MO, I visited the OEIS pages and convinced myself that there is a bound with $N^2/\log(n)^c$. I am going to see Erdos's original paper, but it seems that the link directs to a Hungarian (not Hebrew) paper with the topic about iteration of the Euler totient function.
Also, for the paper, I had a hard time to read Kevin Ford's paper (this one) and try to apply that to the multiplication table because of my level...

There are some links and references at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table that might be helpful. See also the answers and links at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108912/number-of-elements-in-the-set-1-cdots-n-cdot-1-cdots-n

Some history is related at https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/Brent-NTDU7.pdf

OEIS A027424

@GerryMyerson Thank you so much for providing the links! Actually I have read some of the posts before I ask this question and... to find the state of the art proof, find an algorithm to compute, or check where is the proof is not really actually what I wish for... Sorry... But in the end, thank you again!

@Henry Also, thank you so much for providing the OEIS link! (Sorry to say that I have already checked this before I post this question too...) One more thing added to the question I ask is like I have also checked the paper of Erdos referenced in this OEIS page. It seems that this is a paper about iteration of the Euler totient function and it's in Hungarian, not Hebrew. So I think it's not the right paper though. But in the end, thank you again!

It might have been a good idea to include in your question all the sources you had already consulted, Jet. I know that what you want is a proof of $#(S_n)<n^2/\log\log n$, I thought that some of the answers or links on those pages might show the way to the proof you want.

@GerryMyerson The sources is added. Thanks for the suggestion!

There is a review of the Russian paper, in German, at https://www.emis.de/classics/Erdos/cit/10426804.htm which also mentions the earlier Hebrew paper.

This is a failed attempt with a weak partial result, I'm posting it for inspirational purposes.

If $m$ have a prime factor greater than $n$, then $m\not\in S_n$. Also, if $m\in\{1,\dots,n^2\}$, then $m$ have at most one prime factor greater than $n$. This means
$$|S_n|\le n^2\left(1-\sum_{~p~\text{prime}\\n<p\le n^2}\frac 1p\right)$$
Considering now the approximation
$$\sum_{p~\text{prime}\\~~p\le N} \frac1p\approx \log\log (N+1)$$
we have
$$\begin{aligned}
1-\sum_{~p~\text{prime}\\n<p\le n^2}\frac 1p &\approx 1 - \log\log (n^2+1)+\log\log (n+1)\\
&\approx 1-\log 2 = 0.3068528\dots
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, the amount of integers in $\{1,\dots,n^2\}$ with no prime factor greater than $n$ is $O(n^2)$.

Yes, this is exactly what I have tried to to when I say "I also tried to bound the numbers $\le n^2$ with a prime factor $\ge n$, but it seems that there is only $\Theta(n^2)$ of them."...

@JetfiRex I see! I'm sorry for not bringing something new. I do pretend to update this answer if I can improve on this bound.
